# CartThrob Price Modifier Configurator add column not working

Tags: add-on, cartthrob

Running CT v2.2.4 at the moment and having troubles adding columns to the fieldtype.

The docs show an inventory column, but I can't see how to add that. Docs are spotty at best.
http://cartthrob.com/docs/fieldtypes/price_modifiers_configurator/index.html

When I click the add column, it adds the column to top portion of field, and I can type in it, then on entry save, column is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're talking about keeping the inventory in the product options field, if I am reading this right. Two things:

- Make sure you have mapped the inventory to this field, in the
  CartThrob settings.
- Keep in mind that you should keep inventory in only one field - if
  you're tracking individual line item inventory using an options
  field, you should always keep your inventory in that field.